# Not calculating the formula properly in C to F temperature conversion (C++)

Tags: c++, formula, equation

I don't understand why the following formula doesn't compute as it should.

F = (9/5) * C + 32

And when the "9/5" is replaced by 1.8, there aren't any issues and it correctly outputs like this:

```
Enter the temperature: 37
It is same as 98.6
```

But for (9/5) it shows:

```
Enter the temperature: 37
It is same as 69
```

Why is that??

Below is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    float Temp_C;
    cout << "Enter the temperature: ";
    cin >> Temp_C;
    cout << "It is same as " << (((9/5) * Temp_C) + 32) << endl;             
}
```

Comment: Use `(9.0/5.0)` - so the compiler will see that these are the float values. 9/5 as integers gives you 1.

Comment: `9/5 == 1` in C++.

Comment: To expand on the above, Here's some documentation on [Integer literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) and [Floating point literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal).